# Certificates error when implementing one-way and mutual HTTPS endpoints in a single project

Tags: https, mule

I've ran into an issue where if I want to use multiple outbound HTTPS connections - some that require mutual authentication, and some that do not, the connections that **do not** require two-way authentication will raise errors.

Initially, having solely one-way HTTPS connections work fine when I configure an empty (i.e. no keystores) HTTPS connector for the endpoint to reference. Once I add in other outbound HTTPS connections that require two-way authentication (along with their own associated HTTPS connectors including keystores), I can no longer make connections to the one-way endpoints; Mule returns the error: "unable to find valid certification path to requested target".

Here is an example of a one-way configuration:

```
<https:connector name="emptyConnector" doc:name="HTTP-HTTPS"/>
<https:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" method="POST" doc:name="HTTP" host="google.com" connector-ref="emptyConnector" port="443"/>
```

And one for mutual authentication:

```
<https:connector name="HTTP_HTTPS" cookieSpec="netscape" validateConnections="true" sendBufferSize="0" receiveBufferSize="0" receiveBacklog="0" clientSoTimeout="10000" serverSoTimeout="10000" socketSoLinger="0" doc:name="HTTP-HTTPS">
    <https:tls-key-store path="store.jks" storePassword="password" keyPassword="password" keyAlias="keyalias"/>
</https:connector>
<https:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" connector-ref="HTTP_HTTPS" method="GET" doc:name="HTTP" address="https://someservice.com"/>
```

On their own, they each work fine. It is only when the two are included in the same project that I see this issue. Note that not using a HTTPS connector reference on the one-way endpoint will cause it to use the connector configured with a keystore, which will end up causing additional certificate error. I've noticed a [post](http://forums.mulesoft.org/thread.jspa?threadID=7556) on Mulesoft's archived forums from two years ago that has the same exact question. Unfortunately, it remains unresolved.

Additional note: If I import the site's CA's public cert into a keystore and configure the emptyConnector to include it (as a https:tls-server element), then the connector works. However, since the site's cert is a valid one issued by a legitimate CA, I don't believe that this workaround should be necessary - especially if the endpoint originally had worked without a cert in the first place.

This is a rather bizarre problem - does anyone have any ideas or have seen this issue before?